# issue in connecting to Pusher by Flutter

Tags: flutter, pusher

I use the following package to connect Flutter to Presser
But I get the following error
**Error** :

> ERROR PlatformException(PusherChannelsFlutter, Pusher Channels already
> package
> initialized., null, null)

Package:
**package:   pusher_channels_flutter: '^1.0.1'**

```dart
void main() async {
  runApp(App());
  try {
    await pusher.init(apiKey: '1234', cluster: 'us');
    await pusher.connect();
    print('Connected');
  } catch (e) {
    print("ERROR $e");
  }
}
```